# HAProxy installation in CentOS 5.5 32 bit

Tags: haproxy

I am using CentOS 5.5 32 bit for my application server. I want to install HAProxy for load balancing. I found one rpm installer for HAProxy haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64.rpm. But during installation I'm receiving the following error :

```
warning: haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 0608b895
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) is needed by haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) is needed by haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) is needed by haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.5)(64bit) is needed by haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64
        libcrypt.so.1()(64bit) is needed by haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64
        libcrypt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64
        libpcre.so.0()(64bit) is needed by haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64
        libpcreposix.so.0()(64bit) is needed by haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by haproxy-1.4.22-1.el6.x86_64
```

Seeing this error I can only understand that the rpm installer is for 64 bit.
Is there any link to get 32 bit haproxy rpm? I googled but unable to find any suitable link.
I do not have internet on those servers, so I will not be able to run `yum` command.
I have successfully installed the HAProxy in centOS 6.3 64 bit..

-Amit